# Tensorflow: InvalidArgumentError: Expected size[0] in [0, 150], but got 300

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I don't know if this is relevant, but the supercomputer operators conducted an upgrade of Booster module yesterday. After that my tensorflow scripts, which were working perfectly fine before that, raise the following error:

```
2018-06-30 02:21:11.787262: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/consscortk/bin/deep-ScaffOpt.py", line 524, in <module>
    serial_RF=False))
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/consscortk/bin/deep-ScaffOpt.py", line 189, in train_MLP
    MLP = deepMetaPredictor().combinePredictors_datatypes(datasets, mat, serial_RF=serial_RF, META_ZCUTOFF=datasets.args.META_ZCUTOFF)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/consscortk/lib/deepMetaPredictor.py", line 169, in combinePredictors_datatypes
    mlp.fit(datasets.x_crossval['lhl'], datasets.y_crossval['lhl'])
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/consscortk/lib/ANN_functions.py", line 324, in fit
    _, c, p = self.sess.run([self.optimizer, self.cost, self.pred], feed_dict={self.x: batch_x, self.y: batch_y})
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
InvalidArgumentError: Expected size[0] in [0, 150], but got 300
     [[Node: Slice = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_1_0_1, Slice/begin, gradients/sub_grad/Shape_1)]]

Caused by op u'Slice', defined at:
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scoop/_control.py", line 127, in runFuture
    future.resultValue = future.callable(*future.args, **future.kargs)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 252, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, path_name)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/consscortk/bin/deep-ScaffOpt.py", line 524, in <module>
    serial_RF=False))
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/consscortk/bin/deep-ScaffOpt.py", line 189, in train_MLP
    MLP = deepMetaPredictor().combinePredictors_datatypes(datasets, mat, serial_RF=serial_RF, META_ZCUTOFF=datasets.args.META_ZCUTOFF)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/consscortk/lib/deepMetaPredictor.py", line 167, in combinePredictors_datatypes
    random_state=datasets.random_state)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/consscortk/lib/ANN_functions.py", line 235, in __init__
    self.cost = tf_group_RMSE(self.y, self.pred, matrices.assaysize_vec, matrices.group_matrix) \
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/consscortk/lib/ConsScoreTK_Statistics.py", line 1261, in tf_group_RMSE
    Y = tf.slice(Y, [0], [b_molnum])
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 650, in slice
    return gen_array_ops._slice(input_, begin, size, name=name)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 7093, in _slice
    "Slice", input=input, begin=begin, size=size, name=name)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3392, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1718, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected size[0] in [0, 150], but got 300
     [[Node: Slice = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_1_0_1, Slice/begin, gradients/sub_grad/Shape_1)]]


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scoop/bootstrap/__main__.py", line 302, in <module>
    b.main()
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scoop/bootstrap/__main__.py", line 92, in main
    self.run()
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scoop/bootstrap/__main__.py", line 290, in run
    futures_startup()
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scoop/bootstrap/__main__.py", line 271, in futures_startup
    run_name="__main__"
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scoop/futures.py", line 64, in _startup
    result = _controller.switch(rootFuture, *args, **kargs)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scoop/_control.py", line 253, in runController
    raise future.exceptionValue
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected size[0] in [0, 150], but got 300
     [[Node: Slice = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_1_0_1, Slice/begin, gradients/sub_grad/Shape_1)]]

Caused by op u'Slice', defined at:
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scoop/_control.py", line 127, in runFuture
    future.resultValue = future.callable(*future.args, **future.kargs)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 252, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, path_name)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/consscortk/bin/deep-ScaffOpt.py", line 524, in <module>
    serial_RF=False))
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/consscortk/bin/deep-ScaffOpt.py", line 189, in train_MLP
    MLP = deepMetaPredictor().combinePredictors_datatypes(datasets, mat, serial_RF=serial_RF, META_ZCUTOFF=datasets.args.META_ZCUTOFF)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/consscortk/lib/deepMetaPredictor.py", line 167, in combinePredictors_datatypes
    random_state=datasets.random_state)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/consscortk/lib/ANN_functions.py", line 235, in __init__
    self.cost = tf_group_RMSE(self.y, self.pred, matrices.assaysize_vec, matrices.group_matrix) \
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/consscortk/lib/ConsScoreTK_Statistics.py", line 1261, in tf_group_RMSE
    Y = tf.slice(Y, [0], [b_molnum])
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 650, in slice
    return gen_array_ops._slice(input_, begin, size, name=name)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 7093, in _slice
    "Slice", input=input, begin=begin, size=size, name=name)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3392, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/homeb/eusmi01/eusmi0100/Programs/Miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1718, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected size[0] in [0, 150], but got 300
     [[Node: Slice = Slice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_1_0_1, Slice/begin, gradients/sub_grad/Shape_1)]]
```

The version of Tensorflow that I use is 1.8.0. For the record, the same code works perfectly fine on my laptop where I have 1.4.0-dev version installed. Could anyone enlighten me about the source of the error?

Comment: It looks like one of the functions you call changed its order or arguments or something between tf versions. It's impossible to tell what is happening without knowing more about your code.